# MVC Form Post validation breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, validation

The validation for a form I have is breaking the JavaScript I use for check boxes.

Here is the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("HomeEquityFinal", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="checkbox disabled">
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Terms, new { id = "termsCheck", disabled = "disabled" }) I agree to the <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">Terms and Conditions</a><br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Terms)<br/>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Terms1, new { id = "termsCheck1", disabled = "disabled" }) I agree to the <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal1">Terms and Conditions</a><br />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Terms1)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the javascript:

```
$('#confirm').click(function () {
    $("#termsModal").modal('hide');
    $("#termsCheck").attr('checked', 'checked');
    return false;
});
$('#confirm1').click(function () {
    $("#termsModal1").modal('hide');
    $("#termsCheck1").attr('checked', 'checked');
    return false;
});
```

My model validation:

```
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Please agree to the terms and conditions.")]
    public bool Terms { get; set; }

    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Please agree to the terms and conditions.")]
    public bool Terms1 { get; set; }
```

I believe the placement of the !modelstate.isvalid in the controller is causing issues.  The form pulls everything through in session.

This is part of my controller

```
var notes = model.HomeEquityDetails.Notes;

        model = Session["HomeEquityConfirmation"] as HomeEquityConfirmationViewModel;

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model = Session["HomeEquityConfirmation"] as HomeEquityConfirmationViewModel;
            return View(model);
        }
```

When I submit the form and its validated I can no longer click my confirm button and get the box to check and move on to the next page - it just keeps posting back saying the fields are required.

In the code it has a hidden field marked false. If i change that to true in developer tools I can move on.

The main issue seems to be the breaking of the JavaScript when posting back.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just use `[Required]` to ensure that checkboxes only pass validation if they're checked?

Comment: Why do you have a `[Range]` attribute on a bool? Why have you disabled the checkbox (it will always post back `false` - `$("#termsCheck").attr('checked', 'checked');` does nothing to change that)?

Comment: The checkbox is disabled because the user has to read the terms and click accept for the checkbox to become checked.  WIthout the validatoin when I click the confirm button it checks off the box corresponding to it.

Comment: I used range to cause the validation.  It was the only way i could figure out to get validation to take place on a checkbox

Comment: @TheDizzle, Disabled checkboxes do not postback (so the value posted back is always false - taken from the corresponding hidden input generated by `CheckBoxFor()`) meaning that you model  will always be invalid. The `[Range]` attribute is a bit pointless since it will never give client side validation. But the code in your `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` block suggests you have a lot more problems that just this.